# C# How do I access private class variables from Main() besides making them public?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to access private class variables from Main() besides making them public?  I've searched the net but can't find any solid answers.

I'm pretty new to C# and I heard that making class variables public is bad practice so I'd like to know the correct way of doing things.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good intro to OOP in C#.  Have a read and see if it clears up some things for you!     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx

Comment: you can always use the **internal** keyword instead of **public**.. that way every part marked as such will only be available from inside your assembly (program) but not for other assemblies (other programs, dlls, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you can't access private fields of a class outside of it unless you somehow allow that to happen, whether that's using properties or making the field public itself. However, it is said to be a good practise if you provide properties to the class fields if you really need to access those fields.

Example:

```
class Animal{  // this is said to be a good practise
  private string name = "Cat";

  public string Name{
    get{return this.name;}
    set{this.name = value;}
  }
}

class Animal{  // this is said to be bad practise
   public name = "Cat";
}
```

One might argue ultimately they do the same thing, However, with properties that object has full control of how its data is accessed or modified i.e you can restrict some data members to be read only rather than being set or vice versa or none at all.

Comment: Worth noting that you can do it in one line with an auto property. Just do `public string Name {get; set;}`

Comment: that's true but I just wanted to include the private field there so he can have a better idea of what I mean. Using automatic properties the private field is created implicitly so it wouldn't be obvious for the author to know what I am on about. Also he has included within his question that he is new to C#, certainly every beginner learns it this way first then jump onto automatic properties.